# Why is MySQL not stopping at LIMIT 1 when I inspect a row?

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I've got 12 rows in mysql that match this query, but I'm only wanting to examine the row with the most recent date and capture only that date (timeStamp).  Despite setting the "LIMIT 1" (and I've tried "LIMIT 0, 1"), it still examines all the rows and pulls timeStamp for each row.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT timeStamp FROM postings WHERE city='$city' and STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%a, %d %M %Y') > timeStamp  LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$mysqldate = $row['timeStamp'];

$mysqldate = strtotime($mysqldate);
$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d', $mysqldate);
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = date('Y-m-d', $date);

echo "mysql date is ".$mysqldate. " and date is ".$date;
echo '<br>';
if ($mysqldate > $date) {
echo "mysql date is greater";
}
}
```

Here's the output it's giving:

```
mysql date is 2011-11-27 and date is 2011-12-01
mysql date is 2011-11-27 and date is 2011-11-29
mysql date is 2011-11-26 and date is 2011-11-27
mysql date is 2011-11-22 and date is 2011-11-26
mysql date is 2011-11-19 and date is 2011-11-22
mysql date is 2011-11-17 and date is 2011-11-19
mysql date is 2011-11-15 and date is 2011-11-17
mysql date is 2011-11-15 and date is 2011-11-17
mysql date is 2011-11-09 and date is 2011-11-15
mysql date is 2011-10-26 and date is 2011-11-09
mysql date is 2011-10-26 and date is 2011-11-09
mysql date is 2011-10-22 and date is 2011-10-26
```

I'm expecting the mysql date to be the same for every row.. but as you can see, it's pulling it from each individual row.  Any idea why?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
SELECT timeStamp FROM postings 
WHERE city='$city' and STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%a, %d %M %Y') > timeStamp  
ORDER BY timeStamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Anyway if you feel you just want one row (MySQL should give you just one!) you could not use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

but just `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: thank you.. that did it!  Whew.. messed with that for over an hour!

Comment: Strangely, it still won't compare my dates (I never get the echo), but the timestamp is now the same as it should be.

Comment: damnit.  i forgot to add the DESC.  After adding that, the same behavior is showing up.  Ugh!

Comment: @Andi: I think you shouldn't compare dates using strings. Dates are numbers (they should be doubles) and they're are meant to be compared as is :)

Comment: This was the right answer.  After further investigation, it appears that having all of the above inside a foreach loop is causing my issue.  When I remove that, it works.  Thanks for the help.  I'm off to fight the foreach fight now.  :)

Comment: @ I was converting the strings to dates before comparing (strtodate).  I'm still trying.. going to bed for tonight though.  :)

Comment: Why a downvote? What's wrong with my answer? Please, tell me so I can edit or delete my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "order by timeStamp desc" to your query, before the limit 1.  You'll probably need that in any case, to be sure you get the record with the most recent timestamp.  May also fix your trouble here.

Answer (score 0):

With LIMIT 1 mysql will return only one row.

It seems there is just a typo or some silly mistake of the kind. Like if you wrote that LIMIT into file but forgot to upload it.